# error: no such partition entering rescue mode grub rescue>

Tags: boot, data-recovery, recovery-mode

i have dual boot in my laptop win7 and linux.Accidentally i deleted linux partition.now when i try to boot it is showing following error

```
error:no such partition entering rescue mode grub rescue
```

i want to boot my win7 without losing my data .please help me out.